# extract polygons from tiff

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to extract polygon lines from a map loaded as a .tiff file on QGIS? The original map (see below) of Venice is a scan from a book and has all the lines I need (they mark historical parishes in the city), but it would take to long to manually trace them. I need each parish to be its own entity/polygon.

This image is not georeferenced, and I don't need it to be right now actually. I just find it useful to work on QGIS when dealing with maps.

[image]

Comment: If you're comfortable with Python. You can use an edge detection algorithm with scikit-image.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://opensourcegisblog.blogspot.com/2014/08/image-processing-using-orfeo-toolbox-in.html?m=1

Comment: i suspect the text and stippling would make automated feature extraction difficult. probably easier to georeference and trace manually over it.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that since that would be a lot of tracing... Thanks though!